# Cgoban Java App

Tags: java

Dunno what happen but my app CGoban which is a java app from KGS is not working anymore properly. Dunno why on Ubuntu 14.4 we can't have a proper java as on other OS, but I would like to ask you kindly if you can fix this.

10x,
*I*

Comment: Some error messages? As you start the program?

Answer (score 0):

You can try installing some different java implementation, if you are not pleased with the one you have. There are details and instructions here:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Java.

I never had any problems with the Oracle implementations, by the way, so I would try Oracle java 8, if I were you.